# Router can connect to the internet, computer is connected to router, but computer cannot connect to the internet

Tags: windows-vista, internet-connection, wireless-router, static-ip

To connect to the internet, I usually configure my PC to use the static IP, the gateway and the DNS provided to me by my ISP and plug in the connector to my NIC. Recently, my NIC stopped working, so I bought a router (Netgear N150 WGR614) and using a USB connector (Netgear WG111v3) to connect my PC to my router. The router to PC connection seems to be fine. Also, the router seems to be connected to the internet (tested by trying to upgrade the router firmware using the router's web interface, and also the "i" light on the router is green).

But I'm unable to access the internet from my PC. I'm on Windows Vista. Am I missing something?

UPDATE: I called up the ISP. They had changed my IP and the gateway's IP was also changed. The internet works now, but I have no idea why the router's firmware upgrade attempt said that "No firmware upgrades available" and the "i" on the router was green when I was using my previous IP.

Comment: What happens when you try? Does DNS work? Can you traceroute out by IP? (Also, some routers throw a fit if you configure a static IP that's inside their DHCP range. So make sure you didn't do that.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I get "Server not found" on Firefox. The ISP's DNS servers and gateway are not ping-able. The static IP is not in the range of the DHCP range of the router.

Comment: To confirm: You can reach the router's administrative web pages from *this* machine at the same time it can't reach the Internet?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: That's right. I'm wondering if my previous connection settings that I had is what is causing the problem. It now has the same IP as my router does. I think I forgot to delete that connection, but will that be the issue? Unfortunately, that's my home PC and I don't have any other way to connect to the internet once I reach home, so trying to gather as much information as I can.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz UPDATE: I called up the ISP. They had changed my IP and the gateway's IP was also changed. The internet works now, but I have no idea why the router's firmware upgrade attempt said that "No firmware upgrades available" and the "i" on the router was green when I was using my previous IP.

Comment: Because the link to the Internet was up (even though it couldn't pass any traffic) and no firmware upgrades were available (because the link couldn't pass any traffic). Stupid, huh?